# CSS and hiding elements, making my other anchor links not work

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

This is my site:

shoutkey.com/gigantic

When you click on "More Info", on the first item, it works (it folds a element under with information).

If you try to click this more button on the second, third and so on item elements, it wont work!

First I thought it was the .infobutton, that didn't work for the second etc items but now I have found out that it's the hiding elements with the information, that makes the More info button not working. (You cant click on the anchor link)

How can I fix this in my CSS? z-index? How? Am I hiding the elements wrong?

Comment: The first is not working either for me...

Comment: Sorry try again, the first one is working now

Comment: Actually.. in google chrome it works on all elements..

Comment: Hm.. but not after closing the previous one.. if you open them all one by one it all works.

Comment: Why not post code? Once you find your answer and update your site, future visitors have no reference to what was wrong.

Comment: Why don't you use `display:none` to hide elements instead of setting zero height?

Comment: @DamienOvereem You're right. It works if you open them all one by one, but if you close one, then no other than the first one will work. _ This is the problem

Comment: @CyberDude I tried that too, look at .hidden now. Still working same way, and not fixing the problem that when you close one more box, the other anchor links does not work

Comment: @DavidHoude I would like to, but I find it difficult to post the 'right' code for this. I tried to make a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ExZCv/2/ but it works here and this is a css problem in some of the code on my site

Comment: What browser are you using? It's working fine if you only put `display: none` in your `hidden` class (no height, no margins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the use of your `hidden` CSS class, replace `$(this).next().toggleClass("hidden");` with `$(this).next().toggle();`

Comment: I think it works, but I would like to have the elements to be hidden from start

Comment: OK then simply use `.hidden {display: none}` in your CSS

Comment: check the page, it's updated with your answer solution. Click on the more button doesnt show the element now and the other links does not work

Comment: It's working fine for me in latest Firefox, Chrome and IE9 on Win 7. What do you use for testing?

Comment: Works, tested on my 4s. But does not work for me on my desktop, using latest chrome. Weird, it can be just me or my cache. Answer accepted

Answer (score 0):

I ma not sure if this site is getting translated for me, but what I see from your source code is that  you are looking for Mere info and Mindre info

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.infobutton').live('click', function(){
            if ($(this).html() == "Mere info") {
                $(this).html("Mindre info");
                $(this).next().toggleClass("hidden");
            } else if ($(this).html() == "Mindre info") {
                $(this).html("Mere info");
                $(this).next().toggleClass("hidden");
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

But your html has no where

> Mere info

rather it has

> More info

.  So obviously it wont work. You should first get your verbiage corrected in html.

Thanks

Comment: Please update the site, this is already fixed - this was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's causing this issue, but at the top of your page you link to jquery 1.7.2 and according to the jquery API. `$.live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and above.   Try changing that to `$.on()` according to their recommendations.

Comment: I changed to on(), thanks for the notice, but this was not the cause